# PyQt Bloat and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, binaryfiles, pyinstaller

I am very new to Qt, and have been using Qt-Designer to generate code to interface with programs I am writing in python. However, when I want to compile them into binaries using pyinstall, I get `/dist/` sizes of around 60 mb. When using the --onefile option, I am able to get it down to roughly 20 mb.

I'm certain the bloat is caused by unnecessary libraries being imported because of Qt. Can anyone point me in the right direction of reducing this alarming bloat? I am positive that 20 mb is severe excess for the trivial applications I am writing. Thank you for your help.

Using: Python 2.6.5, pyinstaller 2.0, Qt 4.6.2., PyQt4

List of files generated in dist:

```
    bz2.so
_codecs_cn.so
_codecs_hk.so
_codecs_iso2022.so
_codecs_jp.so
_codecs_kr.so
_codecs_tw.so
datetime.so
_heapq.so
libaudio.so.2
libbz2.so.1.0
libcrypto.so.0.9.8
libexpat.so.1
libfontconfig.so.1
libfreetype.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libGLcore.so.1
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgobject-2.0.so.0
libgthread-2.0.so.0
libICE.so.6
libjpeg.so.62
liblcms.so.1
libmng.so.1
libncurses.so.5
libncursesw.so.5
libnvidia-tls.so.1
libpcre.so.3
libpng12.so.0
libpython2.6.so.1.0
libQt3Support.so.4
libQtCore.so.4
libQtGui.so.4
libQtNetwork.so.4
libQtOpenGL.so.4
libQtSql.so.4
libQtSvg.so.4
libQtXml.so.4
libreadline.so.6
libSM.so.6
libssl.so.0.9.8
libstdc++.so.6
libtiff.so.4
libuuid.so.1
libX11.so.6
libXau.so.6
libxcb.so.1
libXdmcp.so.6
libXext.so.6
libXrender.so.1
libXt.so.6
libz.so.1
_multibytecodec.so
PyQt4.QtCore.so
PyQt4.QtGui.so
qt4_plugins
readline.so
sip.so
```

Comment: What files do you get in `dist`?

Comment: @Janne Karila, Hi, I have appended a list of the `/dist/` files in my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That amount of "bloat" is unavoidable if you're going to link to Qt4, as those libraries are dependencies of Qt4.

In order to verify this, you could use `ldd` on a library to see its shared dependencies. Try running `ldd libQtGui.so.4` and see how many libraries it depends on. Then do the same for all the other shared libraries.

I personally wouldn't worry too much about the size of your executable. As you've noticed, it's mostly down to Qt and this means that the size of the resulting binary is barely going to change as your application grows.

Comment: I kind of get your point, but don't you think for example, ... libnvidia-tls.so.1 is a little bit overkill for an application that demands a measly window, a list box, a dictionary, a set, a random number generator, and a few buttons? Keyword: Nvidia...

Comment: libnvidia-tls.so.1 is probably linked in by libGLcore.so.1 which is in turn a dependency of libQtOpenGL.so.4. Like I said, the complexity is added by Qt and not your application. You could scale up your application's complexity by 2 - 3 orders of magnitude and still find that the resulting binary size is dwarfed by Qt and its dependencies. If space is at such a premium, Qt is probably the wrong choice.

Comment: you're right though there are many dependencies generated, it's just why do I need `libaudio`, I have no audio whatsoever in my application.

Comment: That's because you're linking against libQtGui.so.4 and that depends on libaudio. Use `ldd` and verify that. If you're that keen on reducing bloat and only linking the stuff you need, you could try building Qt yourself and specifying only the bits that you need.

Comment: @CadenOrange, Okay I guess I can take a look into a customized Qt then, it's just too bad there aren't other ways to make everything leaner.

Answer (score 2):

FYI see [Hatchet](https://github.com/rfk/pysidekick/blob/master/PySideKick/Hatchet.py), a Github project to analyze dependencies in an app and rebuild PySide bindings to fit.

Qt5 is moving towards reducing dependencies, breaking up libraries into smaller libraries.  Maybe a pyinstalled PyQt5 app has less bloat.

Even if you only import the modules you need, I'm not sure Pyinstaller or Hatchet would do what you seem to have done, analyzing whether libraries that Python directly binds to depend on libraries that Python does not directly bind to.

A worse problem (to me) is that Pyinstaller freezes system libraries such as libxcb that are incompatible with newer versions of other libraries (that it doesn't freeze) on newer versions of the OS.  For example, my app frozen on Ubuntu 13.04 crashes on 13.10 and an app frozen on 13.10 crashes on 14.04beta.  There are workarounds.

Comment: thanks! the next time I'm up for a PyQt-based app, I will definitely have a look into this.

Comment: Does Hatchet only works with PySlide? or is it compatible with PyQt also?

Comment: The Hatchet project might be defunct.  My guess is it does not work for PyQt.   FYI you might investigate PyQtDeploy, which was just announced by Riverside Computing.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, I built upon CadentOrange's suggestion of `ldd`, and used the command `ldd -u`, which actually prints unused direct dependencies. Using this method of analysis, I was able to determine that most of the above made list was complete garbage, and trimmed the list down to a measly 5 files. For a single directory deployment of the application, I was able to reduce the bloat to ~10 mb!! Hope that helps anyone else who might have the same problem.

Comment: I know this is very old post but i am also stuck with the same issue. Can you list down those `measly 5 files`

Comment: @sundar_ima It really depends on what your program is using. In my case it was a very minimalistic program that required nothing but the pyqt4.*, libpython2.*, and the essentials. For example, if your program does not need `datetime`, then do not import `datetime.so`. There is a way to Python to only import a certain subset of modules, but I dont have it off the top of my head. I hope this is *somewhat* clear? Basically for me, it was around 5 files, but someone else it could be 10. For yours it could be anything, but I can't tell you, because what worked for me might not work for you.

Comment: Can you post your work around/ script for the benefit of all :-)

Comment: I had no script; trying running `ldd -u` on your main application file. This should print unused dependencies; does that help?

Comment: I already did that. Does it mean that I can exclude those unused dependencies from the final executable? Bear with me I have not got it.

Comment: AFAIK, as long as they are unused you should be able to remove the listed ones. You have nothing to lose, if your application fails to run you can always just build it again. But again, you should be able to remove those libraries that are unused. When I mean remove, I mean literally just delete those files manually; there aren't too many of them; if you want you can make a script for this process, I didn't do it myself just because it was a one time deal for me, and I don't regularly program in python. Hope that helps @sundar_ima

Comment: @sundar_ima also .... you might be able to come up with a solution (if you know the systems/platforms you are distributing to), in which you can just have these shared libraries installed onto common pathways (i.e. `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc.). If you install on these pathways, then you will definitely be able to delete every single one of those files anyway, because your target distributions will already have these libraries anyway (just make sure that the version are up to date). However that is a topic that is slightly out of the scope of this question. Just a suggestion though.